# Lightwindow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Has anyone used [LightWindow](http://www.stickmanlabs.com/lightwindow/) control from stickmanlabs?

I want to do some client side validations within the lightwindow and feels it doesn't support that looking at [documentation](http://www.stickmanlabs.com/lightwindow/#howtouse). I used 'Working with Forms' part of the documentation to bring it to a point where the loaded html postbacks to a php successfully.

I'm ready to accept the fact that it does NOT support this FULLSTOP! :)

Uchitha.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the demo and there is no reason it wouldn't support client side validation. You may just have to roll up your sleeves and get to know the JavaScript used in the source. All this script does is embed an iframe within a div on the page so it doesn't work any different than a normal form on a page.

Comment: Hi Chris,

What u said is true. But since I'm a lazy programmer I found this alternative which does all I needed plus the client side validations without me having to understand the component.
`http://huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/`